# Starting IPython with Mountain Lion 10.8

Tags: python, macos, ipython, python-3.3, jupyter-notebook

Prior to last weeks ML 10.8 I would invoke the IPython web notebook using `ipython notebook --pylab=inline` where I was running Python3. Post upgrade everything changed for the worse. A lot of hacking around the filesystem and changing permissions on `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework` from root to myself and I can now run `python ipython3 notebook --pylab=inline` however `ipython` when run without the python command preceding, wants to open Python 2.7. Anyone with similar issues or can anyone give insight as to what is going on here.

Comment: why are you adding `python` to the front? This means you are explicitly asking it to run with whatever Python `$(which python)` finds.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are both doing a great job on complicating things, there is no need for that, the suggested way for "reaching" the right executable is simple as that

```
env python
```

or similar, depending on what is the name associated with the given executable.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected that `ipython` will use Python 2.x. You should use `ipython3` to use Python 3.x.